# SSRS LOOKUP with a fixed Source Expression

Tags: reporting-services, lookup

Here is a seemingly simple SSRS Expression that returns #Error...

From this simple dataset we are using the following LOOKUP Expression (which returns #Error).

`=LOOKUP("Score1", Fields!RowName.Value, Fields!RowDecile.Value, "ScoreQuotient")`

and in this case we want it to return "High"!

DataSet = "ScoreQuotient"

RowName   RowQuotient   RowDecile
Score1           92             High
Score2          58          High-Medium
Score3              95          High
Score4              66          High-Medium
Score5                8         Low
Score6              85          High
Score7              91          High
Score8              85          High

Comment: It looks fine to me, so just trial an error debugging next I guess. I would check upper/lowercase on all field and dataset names, then make sure you do not have any hidden characters or spaces in the `RowName` column of your dataset. Another test would be to replace "Score1" with `FIRST(Fields!RowName.Value, "ScoreQuotient")` as that should give you a valid value to test against.

Comment: Deleted the .data file and the LOOKUP Expression is now performing correctly...   Is this just a standard course of action when things just aren't working correctly?

Comment: It can happen a lot, the other option is to hit the refresh button on the report control toolbar, this should drop the .data cache file and requery the datasets

Comment: @JackR - that's usually step 1 in troubleshooting data related issues.